How to organize blocking method and method with mutable &self in Rust?
let mut peer_poller = Arc::new(Mutex::new(PeerPoller::new()?));
let mut peer_poller_clone = peer_poller.clone();
thread::spawn(move || {
    loop {
        let p = rx.recv().unwrap();
        match peer_poller_clone.lock() {    <---- A
            Ok(mut g) => {
                g.add_peer(p);
            }
            Err(e) => {}
        }
    }
});
tx.send(peer)
match peer_poller.lock() {        <---- B
    Ok(mut g) => {
        g.run();
    }
    Err(e) => {}
}

The run() method of PeerPoller is blocking, so the peer_poller.lock() at site B will never be released. This cause the lock() at site A to never succeed. How can I refactor this code to be more idomatic in Rust?
I understand that one option is to refactor code so that add_peer() takes &self and performs modifications via RefCell (interior mutability). However, I'm curious if there is a better solution. Any suggestions?

Not RefCell but Mutex (or RwLock) but yeah, this is the way.

I don't think you can solve this problem by RefCell, since you want to mutate PeerPoller, however you cannot obtain a mutable reference to it because run() take ownership/sole mutable reference.
You probably need to seperate the data from the method, release the mutex when you are not using it.
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Peer(i32);

struct PeerPoller {
    peers: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Peer>>>,
}

impl PeerPoller {
    pub fn run(self) {
        loop {
            let g = self.peers.lock().unwrap();
            println!("{:?}", g);
            drop(g);
            std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000));
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

    let peers = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]));
    {
        let peers = peers.clone();
        std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let p = rx.recv().unwrap();
            match peers.lock() {
                Ok(mut g) => {
                    g.push(p);
                }
                Err(e) => {}
            }
        });
    }

    tx.send(Peer(12)).unwrap();
    tx.send(Peer(16)).unwrap();

    let peer_poller = PeerPoller { peers };
    peer_poller.run();
}

